# add footer to multiple files

Tags: notepad++, text-editor, flat-file

I have bunch of flat files that are saved in a .txt format.I want to prepend in every file the same footer. as below

`1st line text in file 1
 2nd line text in file 1
footer
 1st line in file 2
 2nd line in file 2
footer`
i could try this in notepad++

`search: ^
replace: Header\n`
but it results
 `1st line text in file 1
footer
 2nd line text in file 1
footer
 1st line in file 2
footer
 2nd line in file 2
footer`
I want the footer only once below the last line in files.
any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you want to add Header or footer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find:

```
(.*)\K
```

Replace:

```
THIS IS THE FOOTER
```

Be sure you check the *. matches newline* box in the *Search Mode* box (as well as selecting *Regular expression*).